# Need to give extra weightage to semi-final and final matches in R code

Tags: r, rating

I got an R code for Elo Ratings of teams participating in the World Cup. So, I tried to do the same for a different league. I am getting the ratings just fine but it needs to have a certain weight for teams which reached the semi-finals or the finals of the tournament.

Here is the R code:

```
library(dplyr)
matches = readr::read_csv('data.csv')
teams = data.frame(team = unique(c(matches$home_team, matches$away_team)))
teams = teams %>%
  mutate(elo = 1500)
matches = matches %>%
  mutate(result = if_else(home_score > away_score, 1,
                          if_else(home_score == away_score, 0.5, 0)))

matches = matches %>%
  select(date, home_team, away_team, result) %>%
  arrange(date)

library(elo)

for (i in seq_len(nrow(matches))) 
{
  match = matches[i, ]

  # Pre-match ratings

  teamA_elo = subset(teams, team == match$home_team)$elo
  teamB_elo = subset(teams, team == match$away_team)$elo

  # Let's update our ratings

  new_elo = elo.calc(wins.A = match$result,
                      elo.A = teamA_elo,
                      elo.B = teamB_elo,
                      k = 30)

  # The results come back as a data.frame
  # with team A's new rating in row 1 / column 1
  # and team B's new rating in row 1 / column 2

  teamA_new_elo = new_elo[1, 1]
  teamB_new_elo = new_elo[1, 2]

  # We then update the ratings for teams A and B
  # and leave the other teams as they were

  teams = teams %>%
    mutate(elo = if_else(team == match$home_team, teamA_new_elo,
                         if_else(team == match$away_team, teamB_new_elo, elo)))
}

teams %>%
  arrange(-elo) %>%
    head


print.data.frame(teams)
```

Comment: Can you show reproducible example for `matches`

Comment: date        home_team  away_team result
 01-02-2018 MCFC        JFC         0
 01-03-2018 BFC                KBFC 1